# UIButton does not work when iterating over an array

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton

I'm new to swift, and trying to learn it through Stanford's iOS 9 course. While doing the calculator assignment from lecture#2 (part 7d), I've faced a problem with a part of my code and I can't figure out why. Apparently, this simple part of my code is causing the unary operation buttons not to work, but it seems totally right to me.

arrayOfDescription is a string array I've defined that gives a sequence of the operations/numbers leading to the value printed in the display. I'm simply trying to find the index of the first operation button pressed in my array (the double conversion is to distinguish operations from numbers) and insert something in the array based on the variable operationLocation if "=" appears in the array before the unary operation symbol, but the code fails here:

```
    case .UnaryOperation(let function):
            if arrayOfDescription[arrayOfDescription.count - 1] == "=" {
                   for item in arrayOfDescription {
                 while Double(item) != nil {
                        operationLocation += 1  }
                }
            }
            }
```

(This part of the code is part of the model, but the inserting part is in the controller which goes:

```
        brain.arrayOfDescription.insert(mathematicalSymbol + "(", at: brain.operationLocation-1)
```

And it doesn't work. The app does nothing when I press the unary operation buttons while it should print something on a label)

To be more specific, the case is part of the performOperation function, almost exactly the same as the professor as written. The operations are defined in a dictionary that covers all the constants and binary/unary operations provided in the calculator. Here's the full function:

```
     func performOperation(symbol: String) {
    if let operation = operations[symbol] {
        switch operation {
        case .Constant(let value): accumulator = value
        case .UnaryOperation(let function):
            if arrayOfDescription[arrayOfDescription.count - 1] == "=" {
                   for item in arrayOfDescription {
                 while Double(item) != nil {
                        operationLocation += 1  }
                }
            }

            accumulator = function (accumulator)

        case .BinaryOperation(let function):
            isPartialResult = true
            executePendingBinaryOperation()
            pending = PendingBinaryOperationInfo(binaryFunction: function, firstOperand: accumulator)
        case .Equals :
            isPartialResult = false
            executePendingBinaryOperation()
        }
    }
    }
```

Btw, I'm sure the problem is the first part I've mentioned, cause everything works just fine when I comment it out. Also, there are many details and I don't know which to mention (I could write the enum, the dictionary, the controller code, etc.) so I hope what I've written is useful enough.

Comment: You haven't posted enough context for your question. We need to see the switch statement, and you need to tell us about what your program is trying to do. What are the data structures you're using?

Comment: The switch statement is almost exactly the same as what the professor has written, but I'll update the question anyway. Actually, I'm certain that every other part of my code is okay (cause it works just fine when I comment out this specific part) and I wanted to make sure if the logic of the code is alright cause the problem seems weird to me.

Comment: Ok, but your readers here on SO don't know anything about the exercise you're doing. If you don't tell us, we can't help you without hunting down the particular lesson and watching it. (I'm not going to do that.) As a general rule, if your question requires your readers to spend more time answering than you spent **asking** the question, it's a bad question.

Comment: And add to your question what it should do and what it actually does.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've edited the question, please let me know if it still needs more details.